# Why does ast.literal_eval() evaluate these two dictionaries differently?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, abstract-syntax-tree

My question is why the dictionary "a", that has been created in a valid manner, is different to the dictionary "b".

In the following code you see a simple dictionary "a" which I want to check with

> a = ast.literal_eval(a)

Curiously, "a" doesn't seem to be a dictionary or anything the python syntax views as valid, because ast.literal_eval(a) raises an Exception:

> a failed: malformed node or string: {':': 5}

The dictionary operation a.keys() returns ':' as expected.

More curiously when 'transforming' the original dictionary with

> b = str(a)

the dictionary b is actually evaluated as dictionary in the second try-statement.

```
import ast

a = {}
a[":"] = 5

b = str(a)

print(a)
print(b)

try:
    a = ast.literal_eval(a)
    print(type(a))
except Exception as e:
    print(f'a failed: {e}')

try:
    b = ast.literal_eval(b)
    print(type(b))
except Exception as e:
    print(f'b failed: {e}')
```

output:

```
{':': 5}
{':': 5}
a failed: malformed node or string: {':': 5}
<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: What makes you think you can pass a `dict` to `literal_eval`?  The whole point of it is to turn strings into Python objects, sort of like the opposite of `str(x)`.

Comment: What's the point of passing a dict to `literal_eval`? What would you expect the output to be?

Comment: I expect that literal_eval() checks if the passed string or node is valid regards to the python syntax.

Comment: @ZackDev But you a dict is neither a node nor a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ast.literal_eval` works with strings or AST nodes, not dictionaries.

From [the diocumentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> `ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)`
>
> Safely evaluate an *expression node* or a *string* containing a Python literal or container display.

So the *dictionary* `a` is indeed a "malformed node or string", because it's neither of those.

When you say "the *dictionary* `b` is actually evaluated as dictionary in the second try-statement", this is not quite correct, because `b = str(a)` makes `b` a *string*. Thus, `b` is a string representation of a dictionary, so it works as expected.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So a dictionary is neither an expression node nor a string. But why does type(b) say it is of type <dict> then?

Comment: Alright, so str(b) turns it into a string representation, while b = ast.literal_eval(b) turns it into a dictionary again, therefore type(b) says it is a dictionary in the end... Thanks @JohnZwink , DeepSpace and ForceBru

Comment: @ZackDev, yep, right! `str(thing)` converts Python objects to their string representation, `ask.literal_eval` converts certain kinds of string representations to Python objects.